# How to relate one select element to another select statement

Tags: php, html, post

I have two select html elements inside a form. These two select elements are created whenever the user clicks the "Add" button. So there are multiple instance of this pair of html select statement inside the form. The code looks like this:

```
<form action="create.php" method="POST">
  <div class="user_role">
    <select name="users[]">
       <option value="1"> John </option>
       <option value="2"> Doe </option>
    </select>
    <select>
       <option value="1"> Browser </option>
       <option value="2"> Project Manager </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
     <input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add User" 
  </div>
  <div>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

If I click the submit button, the $_POST array contains the following values:

```
Array ( 
    [users] => Array ( 
                       [0] => 1  
                     )  
    [submit] => submit 
  )
```

I don't know what to place on the "name" attribute of the second select so that I can connect the two select statements.

What I want to accomplish is that, I want to have a way to refer the value on the second select to be the role value of its corresponding user on the first select when stored on the $_POST global array. Example:

```
User: John     <-- first html select statement

role: Browser  <-- second html select statement
___________________________________________________

User: Doe  <-- first html select statement

role: Project Manager  <-- second html select statement
```

Comment: 1: never call anything "submit" in a form - it shadows the submit method; 2: are you talking about cascading drop downs? If so, you can look into PHP AJAX

Comment: In second select menu add name tag like `<select name= 'role'>` and in first tag remove array like `<select name= 'Users'>` . if you want to concatenate then concatenate after submit

Comment: @mplungjan - Nope, It's not cascading drop downs. There are two selects. One selects for the dropdown of users. And the other select is for the roles. See example below:

John        Browser         <--- One pair of user and role select
Doe         Project Manager    <--- Another pair of user and role select

And the number of pair will grow when the client clicks the "Add" button. Now I am having a problem of knowing which role belongs to which user.

Comment: @BilalAhmed - No, I can't remove the array name on the user select as there can be multiple users. If it's not an array, no matter how many users are added, only one value is passed on the $_POST array.

Comment: i think you should used checkbox instead of select

Comment: @BilalAhmed if OP allows one user to have only one role than why should he use checkboxes ? Maybe thats the UI requirement to have selects, it does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
    <select name="users[1][name]">
       <option value="1"> John </option>
       <option value="2"> Doe </option>
    </select>
    <select name="users[1][role]">
       <option value="1"> Browser </option>
       <option value="2"> Project Manager </option>
    </select>
<div>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Submitted form data would look like this:

```
users[1][name]=1&users[1][role]=1&submit=submit
```

If you would like to add another set of select inputs as users - just increment the value. So the next added set would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
    <select name="users[1][name]">
       <option value="1"> John </option>
       <option value="2"> Doe </option>
    </select>
    <select name="users[1][role]">
       <option value="1"> Browser </option>
       <option value="2"> Project Manager </option>
    </select>
<!-- Newly added by js -->
    <select name="users[2][name]">
       <option value="1"> John </option>
       <option value="2"> Doe </option>
    </select>
    <select name="users[2][role]">
       <option value="1"> Browser </option>
       <option value="2"> Project Manager </option>
    </select>
<div>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If there is a problem determining what index to insert at creation, You would need to modify Your JS "add" function.

There are few approaches - You can store some variable that will just keep the amount of users starting from 1, at each adding You would increment it.

You can also count number of selects and get proper number of next element 
You could also modify structure of Your form to store both selects in div with some class and perform counting of elements on it.

Here is some guidance with jsFiddle with vanilla JavaScript:
https://jsfiddle.net/mrba8dLy/

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. That's actually what I wanted. However, I am having a hard time doing it because the "Add" button is what creates those two select statements. I can't keep track if it's users[1], users[2], users[3], and so on.

Comment: Just modified my answer, try with this suggestions and example inside this jsFiddle, (You have to open the console to see the result) https://jsfiddle.net/mrba8dLy/